# Replace missing values by a group mean

Tags: dataframe, julia, data-manipulation, missing-data

In an `iris` dataframe I replaced some values by `missing`.
I would like to replace the `missing` values in the column `petal_length` by the `petal_length` mean per `species`. The code below does work (means before and after replacing values are equal), however I suspect there must be a more efficient way to do this which does not loop through every row while only in some rows values are missing. Also, creating a dictionary is probably not necessary in a more optimised solution.  Any suggestions for optimising?

```
using CSV
using DataFrames
using Random
using Statistics
using StatsBase

download("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mwaskom/seaborn-data/master/iris.csv", "iris.csv")
iris = DataFrame(CSV.File("iris.csv", delim = ","))
allowmissing!(iris)

Random.seed!(20_000)
for i in 1:100
    iris[rand(1:nrow(iris)), rand(1:4)] = missing
end

Random.seed!(20_000)
iris[sample(1:nrow(iris), 10), :species] .= missing

mean_per_species = combine(groupby(iris, :species), :petal_length .=> mean∘skipmissing .=> :mean)
mean_per_species_dict = Dict(mean_per_species.species .=> mean_per_species.mean)

for row in eachrow(iris)
    if ismissing(row.petal_length)
        row.petal_length = mean_per_species_dict[row.species]
    end
end
```

Comment: Crosspost on https://discourse.julialang.org/t/replace-missing-values-by-a-group-mean/82583/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want (using DataFramesMeta.jl):

```
julia> @chain iris begin
           groupby(:species)
           @transform(:petal_length = coalesce.(:petal_length, mean(skipmissing(:petal_length))))
       end
```

(an in-place variant would use `@transform!`)

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a more optimised way by using `groupby`.

```
for group in groupby(iris, :species)
    group[ismissing.(group.petal_length), :petal_length] .= mean(skipmissing(group.petal_length))
end
```